# How to reflect inheritance and polymorphism in the database?

Tags: java, sql, database

I am new to java and was learning about inheritance and polymorphism.
I have an abstract Pet class and have subclasses Dog and Bird which extend from the Pet parent class.

```
public abstract class Pet {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String color;

    public Pet(String name, int age, String color) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void speak() {
    System.out.println("I am a speak method of main class");
    }

}



public class Dog extends Pet{

    private String numberOfTeeth;

    public Dog(String name, int age, String color, String numberOfTeeth) {
        super(name, age, color);
        this.numberOfTeeth = numberOfTeeth;
    }

    public String getNumberOfTeeth() {
        return numberOfTeeth;
    }

    public void setNumberOfTeeth(String numberOfTeeth) {
        this.numberOfTeeth = numberOfTeeth;
    }

    public void playFetch() {
        System.out.println("dog is playing fetch");
    }
}



public class Bird extends Pet{

    private int flapsPerSecond;

    public Bird(String name, int age, String color, int flapsPerSecond) {
        super(name, age, color);
        this.flapsPerSecond = flapsPerSecond;
    }

    public void fly() {
        System.out.println("the bird is flying");
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to create a database for the pets objects. The dilemma is that I am not sure if I should create separate tables for the Dog and Bird class or should just have the one single Pet table. In the front end, I am trying to implement functions specific to the type of pet. For example, if the object type is Dog, then create a button that makes a barking sound. And if the object type is Bird, then create a button that makes birds' wings flapping noise. I was thinking of creating a column called 'Species' on the Pet Table and it state whether the Pet is a Dog or a Bird. And when we pull the data from the database, if we see that Species string value is Dog, then create appropriate buttons accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple strategies to store polymorphism classes in the database.

Take a look [at the Hibernate-ORM docs section 2.11 Inheritence](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance). Those 5 subsections are basically 5 different strategies. Each has trade-offs on query efficiency, data size, etc.

For example, you can put Bird and Dog and Pet:

- or in a single table (Pet). This means that the column Pet.flapsPerSecond is null for a dog
- or in 3 different tables (Pet, Bird, Dog). This means that loading a dog requires querying both Dog and Pet.
- or in 2 tables (Bird, Dog). This mean to query all pets, you need to union results after running the queries.
- ...

The examples here are just the tip of the icebergs of the trade-offs.